# Make a person walk faster when standing on plane/panel in Unity?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

Is it possible to make a person walk faster when standing on plane/panel in Unity without writing a lot of code? If so how?

I am using the standard asset first person movement prefab.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a trigger to the plane and then write a script to check, if an object with a tag "Player" is inside it (don't forget to set the players tag to "Player") . Make the speed variable in the player movement script to public so that other scripts can access it. Then when the player is in trigger set the speed variable higher, and when ever the player leaves the trigger set the speed back to normal. To check if player is in trigger use this:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider col){
    if(col.tag == "Player"){
        col.GetComponent<YOUR MOVE SCRIPT NAME>().SPEED_VARIABLE += SPEED BOOST VALUE;}}
```

To check if the player exits the trigger use this:

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider col){
    if(col.tag == "Player"){
        col.GetComponent<YOUR MOVE SCRIPT NAME>().SPEED_VARIABLE -= SPEED BOOST VALUE;}}
```

Then make sure the increment and decrement of the speed is only called once or else the speed will be constantly incremented and will not fully return back when the player exits the trigger.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Vadium, what happens if you have thousands of planes? Would you want a script on every single one checking for an object tagged player? It would make much more sense to place one script on the player to do similar to what you said.

Comment: Yes you're right, it would be better if it's on the player in case of many planes.

Answer (score 1):

The first person prefab should have public walking and running speed properties. You should create another script attached to the player. You need the OnCollisionEnter and OnCOllisionExit methods in the class. When OnCollisionEnter is triggered, You should check if the tag for the collider is something like "move_quick". If so, the script should turn up the values and when OnCollisionExit is triggered, you should reset those values.

Comment: This answer by UDXS will only work if your planes have different colliders. By that I mean, if your 'slow speed' plane has a different collider to your 'fast speed' plane then this will work. I implemented something similar to this in a 2D game with no colliders. I had a character and its position was compared to a grid of tile types. The character would periodically check what tile it was on and adjust its speed accordingly (I.e slow speed for water tile, fast speed for dirt tile).

Answer (score 0):

Well, when `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` is good for some purposes, here I would recommend you to use `Physics.Raycast()` you can easily set layers that you can hit by specifying the `LayerMask`. And the raycast to the ground will require very small distance to detect the collision, so it would be very good from performance point of view.

Also it will give you more accurate movement speed detection. Imagine that you have some puddle, you can attach to it mesh collider of any form and the speed will be decreased(increased) if you stand right on that puddle.

You can do this easily by:

```
_playerCurrentSpeed = Speed;
if(Physics.Raycast(....., BadGroundLayerMask)) { 
    _playerCurrentSpeed -= 10; 
}
Move(_playerCurrentSpeed);
```

Edit:
Also you don't care about using `GetComponent<>();` or comparing `tag`. Comparing tag for example is very performance heavy.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this pretty simply, I believe.

Like others have said, use the collider to determine if you are on the plane. If you are, then multiply the walk speed or call a different method, like `run ()`.